# WSE 2.0 web service client in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, wse

I'm trying to consume an old web service provided by a third party.
This WS uses DIME for attachments.

AFAIK in WCF is not possible for application/dime response content type to work, so I added a Framework 2.0 class library to my solution in order to use WSE obsolete web service client and proxy classes.

Can I build a client to consume a WS with DIME attachments? If so, how can I build an obsolete WSE 2.0 client in a recent Visual Studio environment?

Comment: The answer is that you should run away from this third party as fast as you can. If they are so incompetent as to still be using DIME, then they are probably not competent as business partners.

Comment: Search for [wcf dime support](https://www.google.com/search?q=wcf+dime+support)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a working solution to this problem, using [WSE 3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/webservices/webservices/building/wse/default.aspx).
Using WSE it can be changed the default service proxy, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824597.aspx). Basically:

- Add reference to `Microsoft.Web.Services2.dll`
- Add service reference to the service with DIME attachments
- **Manually change** the extended class in the **auto-generated** `Reference.cs` file to `Microsoft.Web.Services2.WebServicesClientProtocol`

This will give you access to the `ResponseSoapContext` member of the service client.
The `ResponseSoapContext` contains the `Attachments` member: it's a collection of the DIME attachments of the last executed web method.

Comment: You might want to change the phrase "using WSE 3.0" to "using WSE 2.0" as your solution does not seem to using v3 at all.

Answer (score -2):

Web Service Enhancements 3 (WSE 3) is not officially supported since Visual Studio 2008. The reason is that Microsoft wants you to migrate your code to WCF. Check out the step-by-step blog link below with screenshots on how to enable WSE in Visual Studio. In theory, it should work in Visual Studio 2013.

[Enable Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 3.0 in Visual Studio 2012, 2010 and 2008](http://digantakumar.com/2010/06/04/wse-3-in-visual-studio-2008-and-2010/).